# sabre: Did not find a hosted air segment in reservation

Tags: sabre

The service [GetPassengerDataRQ](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/sabre_sonic_apis/soap/check_in/get_passenger_data) responds me with the message:

```
Did not find a hosted air segment in reservation
```

I'am using ItineraryRef from [create passenger name record](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_apis/air/book/create_passenger_name_record) response
[(Here is the response)](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c009ac0fc6436b3c9c27e486b30fe42c)  and here is the request to [Get Passenger Data](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/97081a5dbabaeccec0330bcc64c6b744)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to retrieve a PNR by record locator, you should be using either TravelItineraryReadRQ or getReservationRQ.

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/management/itinerary/get_itinerary/

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/management/itinerary/Retrieve_Itinerary

Comment: thanks Bruno, now i will try to check-in but i have not a PassengerID, do you know how to obtain it or generate it? thanks

Comment: Are you developing for an airline? Bear in mind check-in services are intended for AS customers only. 

Target Audience
Sabre Airline Solutions

Comment: its correct Bruno, im developing for an airline, thanks